# Finding a finite subcover of a compact set from the finite subcover of the space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact space and $A\subseteq X$ be a compact set.
Let $\mathcal{U}_A$ be a cover of $A$ with open sets in $X$ and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a cover of $X$ s.t. $\mathcal{U}_A\subseteq \mathcal{U}$. Is it true that there exists $\mathcal{U}'$ a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$, s.t. $\mathcal{U}'_A=\{ U\in \mathcal{U}' \vert U\cap A\neq\emptyset\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}_A$?

If yes, how to prove it, or if no, provide a counterexample.

If in general the answer is no, in which conditions can the answer be affirmative?

Comment: Are you *defining* $\mathcal{U'} \cap A$ in the final sentence of the first paragraph? Because $\mathcal{U'}$ is a set of *subsets* of $X$, but $A$ is a set of *points* of $X$, so the usual definition of intersection doesn't seem to make sense here.

Comment: What is the purpose of $\mathcal U_A$? Do you mean "... is a finite subcover of  $\mathcal U_A$"?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, $\mathcal{U}'\cap A$ is a family of sets $U\cap A$ s.t. $U$ moves through $\mathcal{U}'$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I use $\mathcal{U}_A$ for the definition of compact set, i.e. a set $A$ is compact in $X$ if for any cover of $A$ with open sets in $X$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: Then $\mathcal U_A$ is not needed since you do not have to define what compact is.

Comment: @PaulFrost $\mathcal{U}_A$ is needed. I didn't understand your first question at start. I edited the question and now I think it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but then you mean $\mathcal U'_A = \{ U \in \mathcal U' \mid U \cap A \ne \emptyset \}$ or something like that. Or perhaps that your $\mathcal U' \cap A$ is a refinement of $\mathcal U_A$ - it cannot be a subcover of $\mathcal U_A$.

Comment: I suppose by $\mathcal{U}'_A$ you mean a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}_A$. In that case $\mathcal{U}'_A\cap A=\mathcal{U}'\cap A$ and finding one of $\mathcal{U}'_A$ or $\mathcal{U}'\cap A$ is enough, but yes, the correct definition of the subcover should be the one you propose. I'll edit it in my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you can show is that there exist finite subcovers $\mathcal U'$ of $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal U'_A$ of $\mathcal U_A$ such that $\mathcal U'_A \subset \mathcal U'$. To see that, choose any finite subcovers $\mathcal U''$ of $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal U'_A$ of $\mathcal U_A$ and let $\mathcal U' = \mathcal U'' \cup \mathcal U'_A$.

Let us now consider the following example: $X = [0,3], A = [1,2]$, $\mathcal U_A = \{ (0,2), (1,3) \}$ and $\mathcal  U = \{ (0,2), (1,3), [0,3] \}$. Each finite subcover of $\mathcal  U$ must contain $U = [0,3]$. But then $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$, but $U \notin \mathcal U_A$.

The only sufficient condition that I can imagine is that $\mathcal U$ has the property that if $U \in \mathcal U$ intersects $A$, then $U \in \mathcal U_A$. But this is trivial.

Comment: In the example you provide I don't see why you must always take $\left[0,3\right]$ in $\mathcal{U}$? $\mathcal{U}_1=\{[0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(2,3]\}$ is also a cover of $X$, $\mathcal{U}_A \subseteq \mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U}_A=\{ U\in \mathcal{U}_1 \vert U \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a subcover, it is only a refinement.